# How to get top 10 Cases from gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a sample gridview data on below which without using a database. I am using data bind on excel file to load the data on gridview.

```
id sal
1 101
2 102
3 103
4 104
5 105
6 106
7 107
8 108
9 109
10 110
11 111
12 112
```

I wanted to get the result of top 10 values from the gridview.

I am using this code but it only return me top 3 result and the following 4th to 10th is repeated with same result:

```
double NONSPRMaxV1 = 0;

double NONSPRMaxV2 = 0;

double NONSPRMaxV3 = 0;

double NONSPRMaxV4 = 0;

double NONSPRMaxV5 = 0;

double NONSPRMaxV6 = 0;

double NONSPRMaxV7 = 0;

double NONSPRMaxV8 = 0;

double NONSPRMaxV9 = 0;

double NONSPRMaxV10 = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < grvData.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (grvData.Rows[i].Cells[23].Text == "OPEN" && grvData.Rows[i].Cells[28].Text == "NO")
    {
        if (Convert.ToDouble(grvData.Rows[i].Cells[18].Text) > NONSPRMaxV1)
        {
            NONSPRMaxV1 = Convert.ToDouble(grvData.Rows[i].Cells[18].Text);
        }
        NONSPR4.Text = Convert.ToString(Math.Round(NONSPRMaxV1));

        if (Convert.ToDouble(grvData.Rows[i].Cells[18].Text) > NONSPRMaxV2 && Convert.ToDouble(grvData.Rows[i].Cells[18].Text) < Convert.ToDouble(NONSPR4.Text))
        {
            NONSPRMaxV2 = Convert.ToDouble(grvData.Rows[i].Cells[18].Text);
        }
        NONSPR8.Text = Convert.ToString(Math.Round(NONSPRMaxV2));

        if (Convert.ToDouble(grvData.Rows[i].Cells[18].Text) > NONSPRMaxV3 && Convert.ToDouble(grvData.Rows[i].Cells[18].Text) < Convert.ToDouble(NONSPR8.Text))
        {
            NONSPRMaxV3 = Convert.ToDouble(grvData.Rows[i].Cells[18].Text);
        }
        NONSPR12.Text = Convert.ToString(Math.Round(NONSPRMaxV3));


        if (Convert.ToDouble(grvData.Rows[i].Cells[18].Text) > NONSPRMaxV4 && Convert.ToDouble(grvData.Rows[i].Cells[18].Text) < Convert.ToDouble(NONSPR12.Text))
        {
            NONSPRMaxV4 = Convert.ToDouble(grvData.Rows[i].Cells[18].Text);
        }
        NONSPR16.Text = Convert.ToString(Math.Round(NONSPRMaxV4));


        if (Convert.ToDouble(grvData.Rows[i].Cells[18].Text) > NONSPRMaxV5 && Convert.ToDouble(grvData.Rows[i].Cells[18].Text) < Convert.ToDouble(NONSPR16.Text))
        {
            NONSPRMaxV5 = Convert.ToDouble(grvData.Rows[i].Cells[18].Text);
        }
        NONSPR20.Text = Convert.ToString(Math.Round(NONSPRMaxV5));


        if (Convert.ToDouble(grvData.Rows[i].Cells[18].Text) > NONSPRMaxV6 && Convert.ToDouble(grvData.Rows[i].Cells[18].Text) < Convert.ToDouble(NONSPR20.Text))
        {
            NONSPRMaxV6 = Convert.ToDouble(grvData.Rows[i].Cells[18].Text);
        }
        NONSPR24.Text = Convert.ToString(Math.Round(NONSPRMaxV6, 0));


        if (Convert.ToDouble(grvData.Rows[i].Cells[18].Text) > NONSPRMaxV7 && Convert.ToDouble(grvData.Rows[i].Cells[18].Text) < Convert.ToDouble(NONSPR24.Text))
        {
            NONSPRMaxV7 = Convert.ToDouble(grvData.Rows[i].Cells[18].Text);
        }
        NONSPR28.Text = Convert.ToString(Math.Round(NONSPRMaxV7, 0));


        if (Convert.ToDouble(grvData.Rows[i].Cells[18].Text) > NONSPRMaxV8 && Convert.ToDouble(grvData.Rows[i].Cells[18].Text) < Convert.ToDouble(NONSPR28.Text))
        {
            NONSPRMaxV8 = Convert.ToDouble(grvData.Rows[i].Cells[18].Text);
        }
        NONSPR32.Text = Convert.ToString(Math.Round(NONSPRMaxV8, 0));

        if (Convert.ToDouble(grvData.Rows[i].Cells[18].Text) > NONSPRMaxV9 && Convert.ToDouble(grvData.Rows[i].Cells[18].Text) < Convert.ToDouble(NONSPR32.Text))
        {
            NONSPRMaxV9 = Convert.ToDouble(grvData.Rows[i].Cells[18].Text);
        }
        NONSPR36.Text = Convert.ToString(Math.Round(NONSPRMaxV9, 0));


        if (Convert.ToDouble(grvData.Rows[i].Cells[18].Text) > NONSPRMaxV10 && Convert.ToDouble(grvData.Rows[i].Cells[18].Text) < Convert.ToDouble(NONSPR36.Text))
        {
            NONSPRMaxV10 = Convert.ToDouble(grvData.Rows[i].Cells[18].Text);
        }
        NONSPR40.Text = Convert.ToString(Math.Round(NONSPRMaxV10, 0));
```

Help! Thank you.

Result:

112
111
110
107
107
107
107
107
107
107

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me always the best solution to save all data into a List, and then order it with Linq.
I hope this help!

```
    List<double> nums = new List<double>();

        for (int i = 0; i < grvData.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (grvData.Rows[i].Cells[23].Text == "OPEN" && grvData.Rows[i].Cells[28].Text == "NO")
            {
                nums.Add(Convert.ToDouble(grvData.Rows[i].Cells[18].Text));
            }
        }

        nums = nums.OrderByDescending(n => n).ToList();

        NONSPR4.Text = nums[0].ToString();
        NONSPR8.Text = nums[1].ToString();
        NONSPR12.Text = nums[2].ToString();
        NONSPR16.Text = nums[3].ToString();
        NONSPR20.Text = nums[4].ToString();
        NONSPR24.Text = nums[5].ToString();
        NONSPR28.Text = nums[6].ToString();
        NONSPR32.Text = nums[7].ToString();
        NONSPR36.Text = nums[8].ToString();
        NONSPR40.Text = nums[9].ToString();
```

Comment: Great! This was my first answer in StackOverfolw :)

Comment: Well, That's good. :) Glad to have your help. Been solving this for 1 hours and now it's all good thanks to you.